# Fluent nHibernate SchemaUpdate not working

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate

I`m using Fluent nHibernate code first, I had Nullable column, then changed to .Not.Nullable()
but my column is still Nullable

Here is my configuration

```
 public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(x =>
             {
                 var factory = Fluently.Configure()
                     .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString
                         (c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DefaultConnection")))
                     .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Users>()
                         .Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(p => "Id"), ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"))
                         .Conventions.Setup(c => c.Add(AutoImport.Never())))
                     .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(true, true));

                 return factory.BuildSessionFactory();
             }).InSingletonScope();
        }
```

Comment: `SchemaUpdate` fails silently, can you please append the log to your question?

Or look in `.Exceptions` there might be something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK SchemaUpdate will not touch existing columns because it won't handle edge cases, e.g. what happens if the column already contains null values?

Your options:

- add the notnull constraint manually
- recreate the Schema using SchemaExport

Comment: Thanks for that, makes sense. I was scratching my head for a long time trying to figure this out. It would have been really helpful if it had put in a comment saying it needed to be done manually or blown up straight away.